# It's fat but not big

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, internet-explorer-8

The big fat search box. What else?

Internet Explorer 8.0

[image]

Comment: Not fat on Internet Explorer 9.0, consider an upgrade? Wonder what goes wrong there, though... :)

Comment: @Tom: personally I use Chrome. I discovered this while testing [Search box auto expansion moves the cursor during typing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102234/)

Comment: No-Repro on Windows 7 Professional, 32-bit.

Comment: that would be cause css obviously hates me ... will sort this out

Comment: happens in IE9 but only in compatability mode. and in that mode the site looks pretty horrible anyway

Comment: @tombull89: that's weird. I tested it on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, with one exception: the layout will be *slightly* different in IE8/Compatability mode in that there may be no space between the box at the button, but all other browsers will render this `10px` gap correctly.

This is a compromise in that it's 98% correct in IE8, looks fine, works fine, but differs visually *slightly*...and doesn't involve lots of extra CSS for a 100% identical layout, given all other browsers handle this situation fine.

Answer (score 1):

I can definitely repro in IE9 when in IE8 render mode (press <kbd>f12</kbd>)

[image]